# Do all cells of a plant contain chloroplasts?

Tags: cell-biology, botany, chloroplasts

If the answer is no, then how do plant cells tell whether they need to keep chloroplasts or not? What kind of signals are used, and how are chloroplasts eliminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all cells of the plant contain chloroplasts, but they all contain some form of plastid. When the plant is its development state, they contain proplastids which may turn into chloroplasts if the cells are exposed to light. Other forms of plastids may play a role in storing lipids, amylum or proteins and they form because there is a lack of light (these are present mostly in roots). Chloroplasts are not eliminated from the cell.
 Here you have a helpful wikipedia image:

[image: Plastid formation]

This is a very general explanation though and you should look more into hormones and specific triggers for the formation of chloroplasts.
[Article talking about chloroplasts biogenesis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0005272815000286?via%3Dihub)

Comment: It's interesting that proplastids sort of differentiate. Chloroplasts are often compared to and suggested to have evolved from cyanobacteria. Do you know if cyanobacteria also change their morphology in response to light? The article you provided doesn't address it.